# When does a regex interpret something as a string of many characters and when does a regex use a single letter or other character?

Tags: python, regex

When I look at the regular expression `(foo|bar|baz)` I get confused.

Does the regex say:

- `fo`, followed by  `o` or `b`, followed by exactly one letter `a`, followed by `r` or `b`, followed by the string `az`?
- `foo` or `bar` or `baz`

When does a regex infix operator such as vertical pipe `|`

1. use only **one** character to the left of the operator and **one** character to the right of the operator.
2. use a string of one or **more** characters to the left of the operator and use a string of one or **more** characters to the right of the operator.

Assume we are using Python if the ambiguity in regex flavor is a problem.

Comment: Go fish: https://regex101.com/r/mrdEV4/1

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe it is simply: `"foo" or "bar" or "baz"`

Correct, it's that. Try it yourself: https://regexr.com/7bhqp

The regex you describe in your first guess would be written as:

```
fo(o|b)a(r|b)az
```

Here's another demo for comparison: https://regexr.com/7bhqs

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with where alternation symbol `|` can be used:

- in groups, so between `()`
- in the whole regex

Because of that, it has the lowest priority/precedence out of all regex symbols to allow having alternatives for as much text before/after as possible. If it was to function like you showed with your long example, it would need to have a different syntax to wrap everything that should be alternated.

You can read more about alternation [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).